# TYPO3: how to supress deprecated warnings?

Tags: warnings, deprecated, typo3, suppress-warnings

I tried modifying the php.ini file (error_reporting  = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED), but with no result. There's an older TYPO3 project which I would like to examine, and all these warnings are really annoying..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Had the same problem using Typo3 version 4.2.8 on PHP 5.3. Typo3's code appears to be swamped with error_reporting() commands, so placing one in my index.php did not help at all. Bear's solution below worked fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work on your version of Typo3 but try setting the following options in the `typo3conf/localconf.php` or via the Install Tool.

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['displayErrors']    = '0'; // or '-1' to see other errors
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['errorHandlerErrors']     = 22519; // E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_NOTICE (everything except deprecated-msgs and notices)
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['syslogErrorReporting']   = 22519; // E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_NOTICE (everything except deprecated-msgs and notices)
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['belogErrorReporting']    = 22519; // E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_NOTICE (everything except deprecated-msgs and notices)
```

Comment: I found this setting to be working for PHP 5.4+: `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['exceptionalErrors'] = E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_WARNING ^ E_USER_ERROR ^ E_USER_NOTICE ^ E_USER_WARNING ^ E_STRICT;` from http://www.typo3.net/forum/thematik/zeige/thema/115080/

Comment: You can calculate and populate number using :  https://maximivanov.github.io/php-error-reporting-calculator/