# PHP Runtime Notice with fresh TYPO3 installation

Tags: typo3

My server: PHP 5.4.0-8+fastCgi auf nginx server, debian squeeze

I just intalled the new TYPO3 dummy+source release. When I add a new site in backend I get following message:

> PHP Runtime Notice: Declaration of tx_rtehtmlarea_base::drawRTE()
>   should be compatible with t3lib_rteapi::drawRTE(&$pObj, $table,
>   $field, $row, $PA, $specConf, $thisConfig, $RTEtypeVal, $RTErelPath,
>   $thePidValue) in
>   /var/www/meinprojekt/typo3/sysext/rtehtmlarea/class.tx_rtehtmlarea_base.php
>   line 36

Below the error message TYPO3 gives a hint to a bug: http://forge.typo3.org/issues/31353
I installed the bugfix but that has no effect. The error ist still there. BTW the install tool is OK, it gives no errors or warnings.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7502948/282601

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because your php.ini has [error_reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) set to include E_STRICT warnings. E_STRICT is good for development, because it warns you about all kinds of small errors that are good to iron out, but you can turn it off on your production servers without worries.

Comment: exactly, in typo3 install tool you can set displayErrors to 0 (Do not display any PHP error messages)