# TYPO3 error: "Declaration of tx_ttnews_categorytree::getTree() should be compatible with t3lib_treeView::getTree"

Tags: migration, xampp, typo3

I copied a TYPO3 site from the server to localhost, TYPO3 version 4.5.
I set db credentials in localconf and when I launch the site I got this error.

```
Runtime Notice: Declaration of tx_ttnews_categorytree::getTree() should be 
compatible with t3lib_treeView::getTree($uid, $depth = 999, $depthData = '',
$blankLineCode = '', $subCSSclass = '')
```

I found same problem with Google but no solution, or in a language I was not able to understand.
I tried to delete every cache I was able to find, both from files and from db.

**EDIT**

- PHP version 5.4.16
- XAMPP on WIN 7 version 1.8.2.

Comment: What system did you copy it to? XAMPP on Win, Mac or Linux? Which PHP version are you running? Looking at the german forum posts, I understand that this problem is related to using TYPO3 with PHP 5.4 or PHP 6.

Comment: Yes I am using PHP version 5.4. I edited my post with answers to your questions.

Comment: The used versions of PHP, MySQL and other server side components should always match locally and remote. Which versions are used on the server?

Comment: The server is using PHP version 5.3.3-7. If this is the problem is it possible to switch PHP version with XAMPP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there might be several issues with your local installation.
Try this (edited):

- Change your *error handling bitmask* to exclude strict errors, or switch off error reporting in *localconf.php*. Either:

  - `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['exceptionalErrors'] = E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_WARNING ^ E_USER_ERROR ^ E_USER_NOTICE ^ E_USER_WARNING ^ E_STRICT;` (change bitmask, [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502948/typo3-how-to-supress-deprecated-warnings#comment26100320_7503281)), or
  - `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['displayErrors'] = 0;` (off)

This should remove the message in the frontend. You can alternatively try these untested suggestions:

- PHP version: For TYPO3 4.5, 5.2 or 5.3 is recommended. Try switching. [TYPO3 4.5 requirements](http://typo3.org/download#c1983)
- If you don't need the extension `tt_news`, uninstall (Or update it - there is an issue with tt_news 3.2.x, maybe it's obsolete since 3.4.0)

**Sources** (German):

- [typo3forum.net](http://www.typo3forum.net/forum/typo3-4-x-installation-updates/56705-probleme-xampp-umgebung.html)
- [typo3.net](http://www.typo3.net/forum/thematik/zeige/thema/110242/?show=1)
- [lists.typo3.org](http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-project-tt-news/2012-March/003365.html)

Comment: TYPO3 CMS 4.5 does run with PHP 5.4. You just need to reset the error handling bitmask to the TYPO3 default (which includes PHP 5.4. compatibility).

Comment: PS: However it doesn't seem to be possible with `errorHandlerErrors` - is this a bug? http://forge.typo3.org/issues/35154

Comment: I don't know. If the settings does not take effect, please open a new bug report. There might be an entry script that was not taken care of. BTW, TYPO3 6.x has a central bootstrap for all scripts.