# TYPO3 Fluid: suppress PHP warnings in flashMessages

Tags: php, typo3, fluid

I'm building a TYPO3 based website, where I'm using different extensions from the TER. Now two plugins used together produce undesirable results: PHP Warnings in the rendered Website.

The one extension is `tt_products`, which causes the messages, by accessing undefined indices in some array. The other extension is `tkaddress`, which displays the messages.

`tkaddress` is based on Fluid-Templates, and uses the `<f:flashMessages />` view helper to display proper errors, like invalid E-Mail address entered when editing address records.
Unfortunately, otherwise ignored PHP warnings are also caught in this view helper, which gives messages like

> PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in /usr/local/www/apache24/data/typo3conf/ext/tt_products/view/class.tx_ttproducts_info_view.php line 301

This only happens in the live server. In my local development environment I don't get such messages. The verions of both extensions are identical, and I cannot trace the problem down to its root case.

(I know, fixing the bugs in tt_products would be the correct way, but I don't want to modify it)

Is the some setting to suppress PHP Warnings when using `<f:flashMessages />` in Fluid?

**Update:**

Dev-Environment:

- TYPO3 6.1.5
- PHP 5.3.28
- tt_products 2.7.6
- error_reporting (PHP INI): 22519
- OS: Windows 7

Live-Environment:

- TYPO3 6.1.5
- PHP 5.4.40
- tt_products 2.7.6
- error_reporting (PHP INI): 22519
- OS: FreeBSD

So only the OS and PHP Version differ. I also couldn't find a difference in PHP or TYPO3 related error reporting settings (both have `displayErrors` set to 1)

Comment: Please provide us some more info like which version of tt_products you're using, you're php version (on dev and production environment) and the version of TYPO3....

Comment: @ArekvanSchaijk Added system info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP version seems to be causing the described difference between your dev- environment and production environment. I quote;

> [How do I correct this Illegal String Offset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361392/how-do-i-correct-this-illegal-string-offset)
>
> However, this warning message is new to PHP 5.4. Old versions didn't
>   warn if this happened. They would silently convert 'type' to 0, then
>   try to get character 0 (the first character) of the string. So if this
>   code was supposed to work, that's because abusing a string like this
>   didn't cause any complaints on PHP 5.3 and below. (A lot of old PHP
>   code has experienced this problem after upgrading.)

**tt_products**

It seems that you're using `tt_products` version `2.7.6`.

Since version `2.7.6` there were a couple of bug fixes, including some code changes inside the file `class.tx_ttproducts_info_view.php` which may fix your problem as well.

Try updating `tt_products` to version `2.7.17`, see:

http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/tt_products

If the problem still occurs in a more recent version of the extension you can submit your issue on:

https://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-tt_products

**Suppress warnings**

However ignoring any warning isn't  the right way you may look at:

[TYPO3: how to supress deprecated warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502948/typo3-how-to-supress-deprecated-warnings)

Comment: Didn't even think that the PHP Version difference was causing the warning, but some display settting... Upgrading tt_products to 2.7.17 fixed the problem!